# Contents missing using jq to update a JSON file

Tags: json, linux, bash, ubuntu, jq

If we have a `hello.json`

```
$ echo '{"hello": "world"}' > hello.json
$ cat hello.json
{"hello": "world"}
```

and try to add `"foo": "bar"` to it using `jq`, the file `hello.json` becomes an empty file.

```
$ cat hello.json | jq --arg bar bar '. + {foo: $bar}'  > hello.json
$ cat hello.json
```

On the other hand, if we had instead written the new JSON payload to `world.json`, we get the expected contents in `world.json`.

```
$ echo '{"hello": "world"}' > hello.json
$ cat hello.json
{"hello": "world"}
```

```
$ cat hello.json | jq --arg bar bar '. + {foo: $bar}'  > world.json
$ cat world.json 
{
  "hello": "world",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Is there a way to do this **without installing new utilities** like `sponge`?

Comment: You can write to a temporary file and `mv` the temporary file to the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a jq problem, but how output redirection works in shells. When you redirect to a file with `>`, the file is truncated *before* the command is executed.

You have to write to a different file and then copy it over your old file. (Or use `sponge`).

As (generalized) code:

```
$ cmd < file > file.tmp
$ mv file.tmp file
```

or

```
$ cmd file > file.tmp
$ mv file.tmp file
```